# How to mock a function defined inside __init__.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, return-value

I have a module :

```
    Interest
         - __init__.py
         - simple
         - compound

__init__.py:

 def add (x, y):
    return x + y
```

I want to test my module using mock. For that, I want to mock the function defined inside
__ init __.py and return mocked value.
So how to do that ?

Comment: Where are the things that are *calling* `add`? You mock where it's used, not where it's defined.

Comment: You want the function `add` to be inside the `__init__` or inside the class? Could you show the expected output?

Comment: add function is used inside simple.py:
simple.py  
      def total()
           total = add(4,5)
and I am testing total function and for that I want to mock add and return my value.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock it straight from the module where the `__init__.py` is.

```
@patch('Interest.add')
```